# My code in php does not display images stored in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I make a query to display an image in php with the column type `image`.
But it does not show anything.

Attach the code and hope someone can help me

```
$serverName = "localhost";
    $uid = "sa";
    $pwd = "d1mogodon";
    $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                             "PWD"=>$pwd,
                             "Database"=>"Imagen");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn === false ){
         echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $fotoquery = "SELECT imagen FROM Imagen";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $fotoquery);

    while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
          $image = $result['imagen'];
    }

    Header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image;

    sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: so you storing images in the database rather than a system folder?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)